# Is there a way to change back to standard Voice Control when there is no internet connection?

Tags: iphone, siri, voice-dictation

I have just got an Iphone 5 and love Siri, but, it is annoying that it only works when internet is available.

... I was surprised to see that when I turned Siri off, the phone went back to the standard voice control that was on previous devices.

As I spend a lot of time on the underground/transport where there is no internet connection, and, when standing/holding on, it is not very convinent to get the phone out and start messing around - I used to love the fact I could say "play song x"... well, you know!

After going through the options, I saw that when you switch Siri off, it says it deletes your whole profile/history and more which is not ideal - nor is switching every time I get on the train.

... I think the answer is no, but, is it at all possible to automatically switch to standard Voice control when internet is not available?

Comment: @Thecafremo - I only have 6 questions... I think only one has a good answer, and another is written by me.

Comment: So, why didn't you accept the one which was good? And, not for this case, but just so you know, you can accept your own answer.

Comment: @Thecafremo - I know how to use the site! There is one good answer which was written yesterday - Other ones are not proper answers, just work arounds that are far from perfect, which I upvoted, but, hoping for a better answer.

Comment: You know how to use it, [indeed](http://stackexchange.com/users/46311/william-hilsum?tab=accounts).  I just was stunned because of the low rate. You are right in your reasons for it, though. :)